# Why I receive an error using Insert method in tkinter Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

my code is very simple, but I receive this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:/Download/PY/Timer2.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       e1.insert(0,"5") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title(string='prova')
root.configure(background='lightgray')
lbl_title = Label(root, padx=10, text="Timer", fg='black', bg='lightgray', font='Times 24', anchor='center').grid(row=0)
lbl_time = Label(root, font="Times 38", fg='black', bg='lightgray', width=8).grid(row=1)
e1 = Entry(root,font="Times 22", fg='black', bg='white', width=6).grid(row=2, column=0)
e1.insert(0,"5")
btn_start = Button(root, text='START', bg='black', fg='white', font='Times 24').grid(row=2, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to print the value of `e1`, you will realize that it is actually `None`. That's because you have used the `grid()` method just after you have defined the `Entry` widget and `grid()` returns `None`. So, you need to separate them. Here is the working code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title(string='prova')
root.configure(background='lightgray')
lbl_title = Label(root, padx=10, text="Timer", fg='black', bg='lightgray', font='Times 24', anchor='center').grid(row=0)
lbl_time = Label(root, font="Times 38", fg='black', bg='lightgray', width=8).grid(row=1)
e1 = Entry(root,font="Times 22", fg='black', bg='white', width=6) ##
e1.grid(row=2, column=0) ##
e1.insert(0,"5")
btn_start = Button(root, text='START', bg='black', fg='white', font='Times 24').grid(row=2, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Also, now you should realize that your other variables are also `None`. Here is the new correct code.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title(string='prova')
root.configure(background='lightgray')
tk.Label(root, padx=10, text="Timer", fg='black', bg='lightgray', font='Times 24', anchor='center').grid(row=0)
tk.Label(root, font="Times 38", fg='black', bg='lightgray', width=8).grid(row=1)
e1 = tk.Entry(root,font="Times 22", fg='black', bg='white', width=6)
e1.grid(row=2, column=0)
e1.insert(0,"5")
tk.Button(root, text='START', bg='black', fg='white', font='Times 24').grid(row=2, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I understood,  first Insert, then grid or pack, many thanks

Comment: @patel No, it's not about any order. Its about separating them so that e1 variable actually points to a widget and is not `None`.

Comment: do you mean the variable does not point to widget after grid or pack ?

Comment: @patel only if you use it together as return value of them is None.